# Access violation porting 32 to 64 bit in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo

Tags: delphi, 64-bit

Trying to port some code from 32 bit delphi to 64.  Upon compile I get an ACCESS VIOLATION At this line in the 64 bit comple (works fine on the 32)

```
 PByte = ^Byte;

function TyDecoder.findCRLF(pStart,pEnd: PByte): PByte;
begin
 while (Not (((pStart^=13) and (pByte(Integer(pStart)+1)^=10)) or (pStart^=10))) and (Integer(pStart)<Integer(pEnd))   do Inc(pStart);
 Result:=pStart;
end;
```

There were many issues previously porting it from D7 to 10.2 Tokyo but those were rectified by changing all the string declarations to Ansistring.

My guess this may have something to do with pointer types now being 8 rather than 4.

Stumped.

Comment: I rather suspect it's to do with what you're passing to the function, than the function itself. Also, there's no such thing as XE10: please clarify what version of Delphi you are using (e.g. Seattle 10.0, Berlin 10.1, Tokyo 10.2)

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot they dropped the XE notation after 9, its Tokyo 10.2.  The statement causing the violation is this

     pByte(Integer(pStart)+1)^

probably the +1 which appears to increment the pointer address is ok on 32 bit but goes out of range on 64 is my guess.  Id like to cast it down to a 4 bit pointer but dont know how.

Comment: That function may be causing an AV, but it may be a result of passing it something invalid - more information is needed

Comment: Sorry Dave, I added to my response there

Comment: Change `Integer` to `NativeInt` and it works in both 32-bit and 64-bit

Comment: BLAMMO!  Thanks Tom!  She works!

Comment: A better way is to simply get rid of the typecasts altogether. `PByte` (and `PAnsiChar` in earlier versions) natively supports [pointer arithmetic](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointer_Math_(Delphi)), eg: `while (Not (((pStart^ = 13) and ((pStart+1)^ = 10)) or (pStart^ = 10))) and (pStart < pEnd) do ...`

Comment: You received many useful tips from comments above. But overall you should spend some time on the migration center, https://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/migration-upgrade-center You are doing both Unicode and 64 bit migration together, so it would be a lot painful.

Comment: You haven't really solved your problems by using. AnsiString. You've just suppressed them. It's time to learn about the changes and do it right.

Comment: It's also worth stressing that there is no such thing as XE10. The version doesn't matter in this question but for future question is might and you should be accurate about the version.

Comment: @David Indeed, even Quick Reports got it wrong when DX10 first came out, they labeled everything widely as XE10. I actually submitted a complaint to them to fix that.

Comment: @Remy: not just PAnsiChar in older versions: PAnsiChar and PWideChar (and PChar, no matter to what it mapped) could do pointer math already.

Answer (score 6):

You were already told that you can use `NativeInt` (or `NativeUInt`) to get an integer the size of a pointer. But your expression is still needlessly complicated for Delphi 10.2. Delphi's `PByte` (not yours, so **don't define it yourself**) can do pointer math, so try:

```
function TyDecoder.findCRLF(pStart, pEnd: PByte): PByte;
begin
  while (not (((pStart[0] = 13) and (pStart[1] = 10)) or (pStart[0] = 10))) and
        (pStart < pEnd) do
    Inc(pStart);    
  Result := pStart;
end;
```

Instead of `pStart[0]` you can use `pStart^` and instead of `pStart[1]` you can use `(pStart + 1)^`, if you prefer that.

Also read the [online documentation about pointer math in Delphi](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Pointer_Math_(Delphi)).

Comment: Thank you Rudy for explaining and it was amazingly helpful advice.  The code in this example was written in 2003 and the architect lost to time.  I assume it was needlessly complex even then.  If I wind up rewriting this section of code, your answer will come in very handy then as well.

Comment: @Richard: In Delphi 7, there was no pointer math for any type but PChar, so you either had to resort to PChar casts or to casting pointers to integers. The PChar cast was more elegant (IMO), but not so many knew of this, so they cast to Integers.